# Service monitor issue in Prometheus operator

Tags: prometheus-operator

I have service and servicemonitor defined as below,

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-application
  labels:
    app: example-application
    teamname: neon
spec:
  selector:
    app: example-application
  ports:
  - name: backend
    port: 8080
```

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-application
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-application
  endpoints:
  - port: backend
    path: /prometheus
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - testns
  targetLabels:
    - teamname
```

Pods are all available.I have tested the service.

But the Targets are showing as DOWN in Prometheus.Please let me know what I am missing.

[image]

Comment: make sure that you have specified the right path, `/prometheus`?

Comment: @KamolHasan ... Thanks for your response...Is there anywhere I need to define this path? I have only mentioned this path in the service monitor as shown in the code above.Please let me know if there is anywhere I need to add this path.

Comment: can you port forward with https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd and try `curl http://example-application.testns:8080/prometheus` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the missing piece..I had to expose metrics in the application on that path..

So I followed this article  https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/simple-management-of-prometheus-monitoring-pipeline-with-the-prometheus-operator-b445da0e0d1a

For an example purpose, I used the same image given in this article as side car container for metrics in my deployment object as shown below,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-application
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-application
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: example-application
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - name: backend
          containerPort: 80
      - name: rpc-app-cont
        image: supergiantkir/prometheus-test-app
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 8081
```

Then added this port "web" to service monitor.

Now its working fine..
[image]